# vb.net zip overwrite files in zipped directory

Tags: vb.net, zip

I got the code to zip the files in the directory. Here it is

```
Private Sub ZipFiles()

        Dim zipPath As String = "C:\TEMP\Compression\myzip.zip"

        'Open the zip file if it exists, else create a new one 
         Dim zip As Package = ZipPackage.Open(zipPath, _ 
              IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)

        'Add as many files as you like:
        AddToArchive(zip, "C:\TEMP\Compression\Compress Me1.txt") 
        AddToArchive(zip, "C:\TEMP\Compression\Compress Me2.txt") 
        AddToArchive(zip, "C:\TEMP\Compression\Compress Me3.txt")

        zip.Close() 'Close the zip file

    End Sub


    Private Sub AddToArchive(ByVal zip As Package, _ 
                         ByVal fileToAdd As String)

        'Replace spaces with an underscore (_) 
        Dim uriFileName As String = fileToAdd.Replace(" ", "_")

        'A Uri always starts with a forward slash "/" 
        Dim zipUri As String = String.Concat("/", _ 
                   IO.Path.GetFileName(uriFileName)) 

        Dim partUri As New Uri(zipUri, UriKind.Relative) 
        Dim contentType As String = _
                   Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip

        'The PackagePart contains the information: 
        ' Where to extract the file when it's extracted (partUri) 
        ' The type of content stream (MIME type):  (contentType) 
        ' The type of compression:  (CompressionOption.Normal)   
        Dim pkgPart As PackagePart = zip.CreatePart(partUri, _
                   contentType, CompressionOption.Normal)

        'Read all of the bytes from the file to add to the zip file 
        Dim bites As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToAdd)

        'Compress and write the bytes to the zip file 
        pkgPart.GetStream().Write(bites, 0, bites.Length)

    End Sub
```

But this code is creating problem when the file is already present in the zipped folder. It gives an exception. How can i overwrite the files which are already present ?

Also, this code is little slow, is there any fast way to zip the files ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'Open the zip file if it exists, else create a new one 
    Dim zip As Package = ZipPackage.Open(zipPath, _ 
                  IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, IO.FileShare.Read)
```

Comment: Error occuring `Cannot get stream with FileMode.Create, FileMode.CreateNew, FileMode.Truncate, FileMode.Append when access is FileAccess.Read.`

Comment: Answer edited. Use `IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite` instead `IO.FileAccess.Write`